# Should the stackoverflow team create a site for IT career questions?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Given that the various sites in the stackoverflow world discourage questions related to career advice and soft skills, perhaps a new site for this kind of thing might be in order?  Or is the thinking that there isn't enough interest for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you think that's a good idea, you can head to http://stackexchange.com and create one yourself!

Answer (score 3):

"[Career Advice](http://advice.personforce.com/)" would appear to be what you are wanting so it is out there.  You may just not know it.

Comment: +1  I was going to post the same answer.

Comment: That site is something of a disaster: many spamlike questions with no community to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider asking such questions on [**The Workplace**](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), which is ["for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). While it includes career development for professionals in general, there are of course lots of IT professionals there.

Another site that overlaps with IT careers is [**Project Management**](https://pm.stackexchange.com/).

Warning: [**Programmers**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) used to have questions related to this (as the name suggests). However, [it is now restricted to "conceptual questions about software development"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). Some career-related questions are still on-topic ("freelancing and business concerns" related to software development), but general career questions should go on The Workplace. See the [[career-development] tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development) (note that most questions are closed).

Answer (score 0):

Really? You want:

> meta.careers.stackoverflow.com

Getting a little long on site addresses eh?

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Overflow format is not well suited to discussions; it is designed to be oriented around questions and answers (that is, problems that are *answerable*).

General programming discussions are much better suited to somewhere like [reddit.com/r/programming](http://reddit.com/r/programming).

Answer (score 0):

It's *not* that there isn't enough *interest*. Those sites remain tightly focused on their stated purpose.

- Stack Overflow - Programming Questions.
- Super User     - Power User Computer-Related Question.
- Server Fault   - Professional System Administration Questions.

*"Questions related to career advice"* are *rarely* within the scope of any of those tightly-focused topics. So, yes, they are discouraged.

Stack Overflow, for example, is about programming and programming-related questions. It can't realistically become a *anything-of-possible-interest-to-programmers* site without losing focus. "Anything of interest to programmers" covers *way* too much territory and runs the risk of becoming a Yahoo! Answers-style free-for-all.

Comment: Good points, but seeing as SO is active in running a dedicated careers site, a careers SO extension would not be completely illogical.

Comment: Surely. There's nothing *inherently* toxic about career talk. The borders that define Stack Overflow's scope are well-defined; but they are arbitrarily placed. The site can't be "anything of interest to programmers." So the cutoff was made and the community defined. But it *could* just as easily *include* career talk, if explicitly stated as such... or a separate site. It just isn't. The SO folks know they can't be all solutions to every problem. That's what StackExchange is for.